# Problem with for loop when downloading species occurrence data

Tags: r

I want to download the occurrence data from gbif website and I use the following R script. When I run the script, I got an error with the following message "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0)". It would be highly appreciated if anyone could help me with this.

My data: [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf9lbmkmuqm6sse/Mekong%20fish.xlsx?dl=0)

My R script:

```
flist<-read_excel("Mekong fish.xlsx",sheet="Sheet1")

##Loop
fname<-list()
Occ<-list()
datfish<-list()

name_list<-unique(flist$Updated_name)

# create for loop to produce ggplot2 graphs 
for (i in seq_along(name_list)) { 

  # create plot for each Occurrence in df 
  Occ[[i]] <-occ_search(scientificName = name_list[i], limit=2)

  fname[[i]]<-occ_search(scientificName = name_list[i],
           fields = c("species", "country","decimalLatitude", "decimalLongitude"),
           hasCoordinate=T, limit= Occ[[i]]$meta[4],return ="data")
  datfish[[i]]<-as.data.frame(fname[[i]]$data)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a different error:

> Expecting logical in D1424 / R1424C4: got 'in Lao'Expecting logical in D1426 / R1426C4: got 'in China'Expecting logical in D1467 / R1467C4: got 'only Cambodia'Expecting logical in D1469 / R1469C4: got 'only in VN'Expecting logical in D1473 / R1473C4: got 'only in China'Expecting logical in D1486 / R1486C4: got 'only in Malaysia'Expecting logical in D1488 / R1488C4: got 'only 1 point in VN'

I think the problem is caused in some fields in the 4th column. I don't have the right packages installed to run your code. But I got a different error (package missing) once i dropped the fourth column.

```
flist<-read_excel("~/Downloads/Mekong fish.xlsx",sheet="Sheet1")

flist <=subset(flist, select = -4)

...
```

EDIT:

This worked for me. `read_excel` assigned column 4 the type boolean. When I explicitly set it to text it worked.

```
library(readxl)
library(rgbif)
library(raster)

flist<-read_excel("~/Downloads/Mekong fish.xlsx",
                  sheet="Sheet1", 
                  col_types = c("numeric", "text", "numeric", "text"))

flist

##Loop
fname<-list()
Occ<-list()
datfish<-list()

name_list<-unique(flist$Updated_name)


# create for loop to produce ggplot2 graphs 
for (i in seq_along(name_list[1:2])) { 
  message(i)
  # # create plot for each Occurrence in df 
  Occ[[i]] <-occ_search(scientificName = name_list[i], limit=2)
  message(Occ[[i]])
  fname[[i]]<-occ_search(scientificName = name_list[i],
           fields = c("species", "country","decimalLatitude", "decimalLongitude"),
           hasCoordinate=T, limit= Occ[[i]]$meta[4],return ="data")
  message(fname[[i]])
  datfish[[i]]<-as.data.frame(fname[[i]]$data)
  message(datfish[[i]])
}

> 1
> list(offset = 0, limit = 2, endOfRecords = FALSE, count = >15)list(list(name = c("Animalia", "Chordata", "Actinopterygii", 
> "Cypriniformes", "Cyprinidae", "Aaptosyax", "Aaptosyax grypus"), key = > > c("1", "44", "204", "1153", "7336", "2363805", "2363806"),
> etc...
```

Comment: Thank Jonas for the help. I followed your suggestion, but it still has the same error. Below are the package and library that I use.

install.packages("rgbif"),
library(rgbif),
library(raster),

Comment: I follow your script but it can do only the first 2 species even if I already changed it to (i in seq_along(name_list[1:1491])). Is it because my list file is too large?

Comment: It could be that you run out of memory or something. The first lines causing an error apear after line 1400. so you could try to do it in several runs and merge your dataframes later. So maybe do `(i in seq_along(name_list[1:500]))`, `(i in seq_along(name_list[501:100]))` & `(i in seq_along(name_list[1:1491]))`. Doing this you also avoid the problematic cells in the last run initially.  If the first two runs work, but he last fail, you know more about where to look for the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonas for your help. It is fine now.